# Clear the Selection of an Item in a ListBox C#

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, selecteditem

I have a multi-select list box. When an item is selected a document is opened in a tab control. When the document is closed I want to un-select the item in the list box. I don't want it removed from the collection, I don't want to clear all selections. I just want to clear that particular selection.

In the OnRequestClose() method;

```
string itemName=workTab.DisplayName;
foreach (QResult r in FileListBox.SelectedItems)
 {
  If(r.FileName = itemName) //Clear the Selection
```

That is my approach but I can't seem to get the syntax and the examples I find are for clearing all or removing the selected items from the list.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Set SelectedIndex=-1

Comment: WPF without mvvm? WPF don't pay its complexity if you don't implement that pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
string itemName=workTab.DisplayName;
var i=0;
while (i<FileListBox.SelectedItems.Count)
 {
  QResult r = FileListBox.SelectedItems [i] 
  if(r.FileName = itemName){
     FileListBox.SelectedItems.Remove(r);
  }
  i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
foreach (var r in FileListBox.SelectedItems.Cast<QResult>().ToList())
{
    if (r.FileName == itemName) //Clear the Selection
    {
        FileListBox.SelectedItems.Remove(r);
    }
}
```